# If Lisp source code is basically an AST, does that mean Lisp macros are language agnostic?

Tags: lisp, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

Can macros (or reader macros even) walk a nonLisp language's AST and transform them somehow? I'd want to run the nonLisp language in its own compiler, not a Lisp compiler

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, most Lisp macros walk a "non-Lisp" language: the language of the macro. :)

Secondly, Lisp macros can indeed be used for expanding structures which ultimately generate some entirely non-Lisp language which is processed somewhere else.

A very common (nowadays) example of this is any one of the available HTML-generation systems, many of which use macros, which ultimately produce textual textual HTML (a structured computer language) that is then ultimately processed in the user's browser.

If you want a code-generating system to be able to use Lisp macros, all you have to do, in a nutshell, is implement it in such a way that it is driven by the evaluation of Lisp forms.

For instance, if you make a Lisp-based assembler for X86, have it so that an expression like `(movl eax ebx)` is processed by means of it being evaluated as a form, such that there is actually a `movl` function or macro that is called. This evaluation could require some context, like a stream where the output is supposed to go, and that could be set up by some setup macro:

```
(with-x86-assembler (:output-file "foo.asm")
  (movl eax ebx))  ;; just evaluated!
```

This `movl` thing is aware of the environment set up by the `with-x86-assembler`, such as some dynamically scoped variable that holds the destination stream and other context.

Since the interior of the `with-x86-assembler` macro is just some forms to be evluated, we can use macros there:

```
(defmacro save-basic-regs (base-reg)
  ^(progn (movl (ind ,base-reg) eax)     ;; movl [<reg>], eax
          (movl (ind ,base-reg 4) ebx)   ;; movl [<reg> + 4], ebx
          ...))
```

Now we can use `(save-basic-regs edi)` inside `with-x86-assembler`. Effectively we have a macro assembler supporting a macro instruction.

Lisp macros can be used to process the AST of some entirely non-Lisp language which is parsed by a custom parser having nothing to do with read macros. Nothing prevents you from writing Lisp code that parsers, say, JavaScript syntax, and produces Lisp which is then evaluated. That Lisp then relies on various run-time support, which may include macros. Some JavaScript loop can turn into a `(loop ...)` form, which is a macro. The Lisp is that code's AST, and the `loop` macro is expanded during the macro-expanding AST walk.

Answer (score 3):

It does not mean it's agnostic. It means it does very little parsing. The structure of a program is very similar to the resulting syntax tree and very similar to a data structure.

Any language AST is a tree so yes. Lisp can walk a different languages syntax tree after the parsing and it can transform it. Any language can since we are talking transforming one tree to a slightly different tree. Non of them would look remotely like the original source code. Here is where the powerful macros in algol languages fail. You cannot tell a programmer to explain the transformation on AST level since its alien for her.

Some algol languages, like [Nermle](https://github.com/rsdn/nemerle/wiki/Macros-tutorial#Defining_a_new_macro), has powerful macros. They are quite different than lisp but they provide the quote unquote:

```
macro for (init, cond, change, body)
{
  <[ 
    $init;
    def loop () : void {
      if ($cond) { $body; $change; loop() } 
      else ()
    };
    loop ()
  ]>
}
```

The magic here is `<[` and `]>` which work as `"` around strings except that the result is an AST. Also the `$` in front of a variable indicates some sort or replacement from the compile time macro function.

I would imagine it would be a wast to make a compiler for an algol language in lisp rather than having it written in itself. Bootstrapping is half the fun.

Comment: @DiamondFox What makes you think Python is not Algol? If you replace aligned spaces with blocks it's pretty darn difficult to tell the difference.